# Rails REST API and Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails app to which its users have two ways of interaction.

Through a web interface and through an API (mobile app and other software).

The functions for the web and the api access are the same, for example a user can write a comment via the web interface (views) or through the API.

What I would do now is create all the controllers with views, and then create a namespace /API/ with its own controllers. The problem now is of course that I have to write the function to write write a comment twice. Once in my PostController and once in my API/PostController.

I learned that Rails = DRY, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

How would I make the same functions available for my views and at the same time for my API (JSON response).

And how would the routes and namespaces look like? I think even if I find a way to not repeat myself it would be nice to have API routes like api/v1/...

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, both using an API namespaced controller and using a single controller.

Since you seem convinced that you can do everything equally within your Web interface as your API interface it would make sense to merge the two, though note that this is not always true.

If it makes more sense for you to use a single controller, then what you need to do is play with the `repond_to` format of requests coming to a single controller action.

Ex:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # will render a view by default
      format.json { render json: @articles }
    end
  end

  def create
    article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if article.save
        flash[:notice] = "success!"
      else
        flash[:error] = "uhoh!"
      end

      format.html # renders a view by default
      format.json { render json: { errors: @articles.errors }
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Comment: In your answer - If I was some other application that needed to consume this applications data, would I request `example.com/articles/index`? How would the `ArticlesController` know that I wanted JSON data? I'm also trying to learn a bit more about building APIs.

Comment: Rails controllers can use the `format` to change the request flow. Nothing ever requests `/articles/index`, it will always have a format either in the URL or as Content-Type: `articles/index.html`. If you don't know what `respond_to` and `format` do and my answer contains that code, don't you think it would be smart to look into this first?